# Form Text Area not going onto more than one line, Just keeps rolling

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I have a form in the footer and contact page of a clients website, its only simple but for some reason the form text area box does not move on to another line when it reaches the end of the box, it just keeps scrolling. The site is live [here](http://www.hpmcontracts.com)

The client wants to be able to create new paragraphs and the content box to resize according to the amount of content input.

I have played around with it for ages but can't seem to find anything wrong. Maybe i
I'm missing something obvious...

My forms code is this, obviously with php code above

```
<h1 style="color:#00b3ff" id="contact-form">Contact us</h1>
<?php if( !$success ): ?>
<p style="color:#FFFFFF;">Fill out the form below and we will respond asap.</p>

<form class="quick" method="post" action="#contact-form">

<input type="text" name="contact[name]" class="text-field" value="<?php echo $_POST['contact']['name']; ?>" placeholder="Name *" />

<input type="text" name="contact[email]" class="text-field" value="<?php echo $_POST['contact']['email']; ?>" placeholder="Email" />

<input type="text" name="contact[telephone]" class="text-field" value="<?php echo $_POST['contact']['telephone']; ?>" placeholder="Telephone *" />

<input type="text" name="contact[comments]" class="textarea" value="<?php echo $_POST['contact']['comments']; ?>" placeholder="Comments *" />

<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit" />
<?php else: ?>
    <p style="color: white;">Thank you for your enquiry, we'll get back to you shortly.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

</form>


/* LOGIN & REGISTER FORM */

form.quick{
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

I cant see anything here that is wrong?

```
form .text-field {
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid #a6a6a6;
    width: 70%;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    outline: none;
}

form .text-field:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #008dd3;
    color: #a6a6a6;
    background: white;
}

form .textarea {
    float: left;
    border: 0px solid #a6a6a6;
    width: 70%;
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #000000;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    outline: none;

}
form .textarea:focus {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px #00b3ff;
    background: white;
}

form .submit {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border: 0px solid #336895;
    width: 40%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    background-color: #00b3ff;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:400;
    opacity: 1;
       transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
       -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
}

form .submit:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Could someone help me please I'm pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: If you want it to be a textarea, don't you need to have it as a `<textarea>` rather than `<input type="text"`?

Comment: Exactly what @andrewsi said. input type text will always be one line. For multiple, use `textarea` element.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
<input type="text" name="contact[comments]" class="textarea" value="<?php echo $_POST['contact']['comments']; ?>" placeholder="Comments *" />
```

to

```
<textarea name="contact[comments]" class="textarea" placeholder="Comments *"><?php echo $_POST['contact']['comments']; ?></textarea>
```